¿Cómo puedo desde C++ trabajar con otra aplicación?
Necesito de su ayuda.
Quisiera desde C++ trabajar con un cliente de mysql sin utilizar bibliotecas propias para trabajar con bases de datos.
Lo que yo pretendo hacer es utilizar la función 'system' de la biblioteca base de C(stdio) para iniciar el cliente de la base de datos y luego poder crear, eliminar y editar tablas.
El inconveniente que tengo es que cuando inicio el servidor el programa obviamente abre el servidor pero pierdo el contexto de la aplicación.
Pensé en utilizar hilos para el programa. Pero no tengo claro cómo esto me puede ayudar a solucionar el problema. Y lo que pretendo son dos cosas: Primero no perder el orden y control de la ejecución, y segundo poder enviar los comandos necesarios al cliente de base de datos para poder hacer CRUD y también cerrarlo.
La prueba que hice fue la siguiente....
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    //abrir cliente 
    system("mysql -h localhost -u user -p");
        //aqui pierdo el ejecución ya que se ejecuta el otro programa
    //cerrar cliente
    system("exit;");
    return 0;
}

Me gustaría conocer qué es lo que tengo que aprender para saber como trabajar con estos casos.
Si no me hice entender bien, también estaré pendiente a sus comentarios y así poder aclarar el problema, y de ustedes a mí las dudas que tengo.
GRACIAS!!!

No se si sea posible hacer como quieres. Por qué no usas una librería?

Como te indica @Mateo, la forma correcta es usando una librería que implemente el API de mySQL. Aquí https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/8.0/en/ puedes encontrar los detalles. Usar system, pipes o incluso popen en este caso es una mala

Solo lo quiero hacer de esta forma para saber cómo conectar entre aplicaciones. Es más un ejercicio de aprendizaje :)

Parta conectar aplicaciones, la forma estándar es crear procesos con fork y crear pipes para comunicar el proceso padre con el proceso hijo o utilizar los mecanismos IPC estándard... pero para eso necesitas control sobre ambas aplicaciones. popen simplifica ese proceso, pero los pipes tienen limitaciones. La otra alternativa es la que te dan en la respuesta, pero evita usar system, especialmente si le vas a pasar datos introducidos por el usuario (usa fork+execve+waitpid)

Bueno, es posible que aprendas más viendo el código fuente de la librería. Tal vez se conecta a MySQL por medio de sockets. La comunicación de aplicación puede darse de diferentes maneras.

El comando que muestras te da acceso a la consola de MySQL. Si quieres enviar y recibir datos mediante comandos usando tu instalación de MySQL no lo conseguirás así.
Cada llamada debe ser un comando individual con el parámetro -e:

Execute the statement and quit. The default output format is like that produced with --batch. See Section 6.2.2.1, “Using Options on the Command Line”, for some examples. With this option, mysql does not use the history file.

De esa manera puedes hacer múltiples llamadas a system para cada una de tus acciones de base de datos:
system("mysql.exe -e \"DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bbdd\"");
system("mysql.exe -e \"CREATE DATABASE bbdd\"");

Recuerda capturar el valor de retorno de la función system, que será el retorno de la llamada a mysql.exe1, para ver si el comando se ejecutó.

1Esto es dependiente de implementación, consulta las notas de tu compilador.

Entiendo. Es decir que no es la manera... Y sabrías si es posible hacerlo por sockets? He estado leyendo sobre como comunicar aplicaciones y encontré dos maneras. Por pipes(tuberías) y por sockets. Es posible?

La comunicación mediante sockets no es algo que las aplicaciones, per se, implementen de manera nativa; debe ser una funcionalidad que implementen explícitamente. Jamás he oído que MySQL la implemente, aunque eso no significa que no lo haga. Echa un vistazo a la documentación.
